# Why did I get return code 200 instead of 201 on my post request ? (Python /Requests/Json)

Tags: python, json, request, http-error

I am using pandas and requests to create a post request, and the one I am creating sent me back a status code 200 instead of a 201.

In this post, I send a JSON from a dataframe. This part seems to be good.
I don't know if the header is good or not, I changed a lot of things in it, without success.

This problem doesn't show any error and the server affected by the request doesn't give any sign too.
The first request give me the access token and work well.

```
def post_json(nbr_requests):
    auth_json = {'grant_type': 'password', 'client_id': 'hidden','client_secret':'hidden','username':'hidden','password':'hidden'}
    auth_response  = requests.post('http://hidden:8080/lot/of/stufs/token',data=auth_json)
    token = auth_response.json()["access_token"]
    api_call_headers = {'content-type':'application/json', 'accept':'application/json','authorization': 'Bearer' + token}
    url_to_go = "http://localhost:8080/hidden/link"
    for i in range(nbr_requests):
        api_call_response = requests.post(url_to_go, headers=api_call_headers, json=json_array_to_send[i],data={"key": "value"})
        print (api_call_response.status_code)
```

Comment: You show us the client code but asking about the server. Show us the server code, namely the relevant endpoint. Anyway, `200` is the default "ok" code. If you want to return anything else you have to explicitly do so.

Comment: I can't show server side code because of confidential issues but with Postman I don't have this status code problem and I get a 201 like  it should. With code 201, their is an insert in database and I can see a result at least.

Comment: Then create a [mcve]. We can't help you without seeing any code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know the question wasn't clear, but if someone got the same problem, you should add a space between "Bearer" and the token in the header.

In my example above you should do something like this :

```
api_call_headers = {'content-type':'application/json', 'accept':'application/json','authorization': 'Bearer ' + token}
```